# Finding mongoDB records in batches (using mongoid ruby adapter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Using rails 3 and mongoDB with the mongoid adapter, how can I batch finds to the mongo DB?  I need to grab all the records in a particular mongo DB collection and index them in solr (initial index of data for searching).

The problem I'm having is that doing Model.all grabs all the records and stores them into memory.  Then when I process over them and index in solr, my memory gets eaten up and the process dies.

What I'm trying to do is batch the find in mongo so that I can iterate over 1,000 records at a time, pass them to solr to index, and then process the next 1,000, etc...

The code I currently have does this:

```
Model.all.each do |r|
  Sunspot.index(r)
end
```

For a collection that has about 1.5 million records, this eats up 8+ GB of memory and kills the process.  In ActiveRecord, there is a find_in_batches method that allows me to chunk up the queries into manageable batches that keeps the memory from getting out of control.  However, I can't seem to find anything like this for mongoDB/mongoid.

I would LIKE to be able to do something like this:

```
Model.all.in_batches_of(1000) do |batch|
  Sunpot.index(batch)
end
```

That would alleviate my memory problems and query difficulties by only doing a manageable problem set each time.  The documentation is sparse, however, on doing batch finds in mongoDB.  I see lots of documentation on doing batch inserts but not batch finds.

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing memory issues with this? Mongoid and the underlying Mongo driver already batch queries with a cursor. This keeps the memory footprint small.

Comment: By the way, you should change the accepted answer to @RyanMcGeary's one - then all future visitos of your question will see the correct one and nobody won't implement manual optimization that is already done by the driver .

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**With Mongoid, you don't need to manually batch the query.**

In Mongoid, `Model.all` returns a `Mongoid::Criteria` instance. Upon calling `#each` on this Criteria, a Mongo driver cursor is instantiated and used to iterate over the records.  This underlying Mongo driver cursor already batches all records. By default the `batch_size` is 100.

For more information on this topic, read [this comment from the Mongoid author and maintainer](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-1335?focusedCommentId=977653&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-977653).

In summary, you can just do this:

```
Model.all.each do |r|
  Sunspot.index(r)
end
```

Comment: thanks for the info @RyanMcGeary, god how have i missed the cursor thing,,, in the link durran specified about batch_size, how can we specify that externally...?

Comment: @RameshVel, I'm not sure if Mongoid exposes the ability to change the `batch_size` per query. That might be a worthy patch if it isn't already an option.

Comment: Nice, And what about other `Enumerable` methods like `map` or `collect`?

Comment: so does that mean by default, the database is hit ~ `n / 100` times everytime?

Comment: @Edmund "Hit" probably isn't the best word to use here, because it implies re-running the query each time. It's a database cursor. Think of it more like streaming the data across in batches of 100.

Comment: @RyanMcGeary link inside your answer is broken. Can you edit/correct?

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos Took me a while to find the same comment. It's been almost 5 years, and Mongoid has since switched from GitHub Issues to JIRA. I think I found the appropriate comment.

Comment: For the record in recent versions the batch size internally usually starts at 100 but then increases to reduce the number of calls to the database. What's great about this also is that it works with all enumerable methods so if you want to gets your records in actual ruby batches (like arrays of 100), you can do: `Model.all.each_slice(100) { |array| ... }`

Comment: One MAJOR catch with this behavior that gets me over and over is that it doesn't work on relations, because the relation will store an "IdentityMap" of all the loaded records.  For instance: `person.purchases.each { ... }` will load all "purchases" into memory, attached to the `person` instance.  Instead, you have to call `Purchase.where(person: person).each` to avoid storing all the returned records in memory.

Answer (score 9):

If you are iterating over a collection where each record requires a lot of processing (i.e querying an external API for each item) it is possible for the cursor to timeout. In this case you need to perform multiple queries in order to not leave the cursor open.

```
require 'mongoid'

module Mongoid
  class Criteria
    def in_batches_of(count = 100)
      Enumerator.new do |y|
        total = 0

        loop do
          batch = 0

          self.limit(count).skip(total).each do |item|
            total += 1
            batch += 1
            y << item
          end

          break if batch == 0
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is a helper method you can use to add the batching functionality. It can be used like so:

```
Post.all.order_by(:id => 1).in_batches_of(7).each_with_index do |post, index|
  # call external slow API
end
```

Just make sure you ALWAYS have an order_by on your query. Otherwise the paging might not do what you want it to. Also I would stick with batches of 100 or less. As said in the accepted answer Mongoid queries in batches of 100 so you never want to leave the cursor open while doing the processing.

Comment: The `.no_timeout` method on criteria saves you from having to manually reconnect: `Post.all.order_by(:id => 1).batch_size(7).no_timeout.each_with_index do ... `

Comment: @rewritten In some cases, this doesn't work; even with `no_timeout`, it will timeout regardless. I don't know what the limit was, but from what I observed, it will timeout if you iterate over the collection for around 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 7):

It is faster to send batches to sunspot as well.
This is how I do it:

```
records = []
Model.batch_size(1000).no_timeout.only(:your_text_field, :_id).all.each do |r|
  records << r
  if records.size > 1000
    Sunspot.index! records
    records.clear
  end
end
Sunspot.index! records
```

`no_timeout`: prevents the cursor to disconnect (after 10 min, by default)

`only`: selects only the id and the fields, which are actually indexed

`batch_size`: fetch 1000 entries instead of 100

Comment: remember to 'Sunspot.index! records' after the loop or you won't index the last group of < 1000 I believe

Comment: Correct. I forgot to copy this part.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the batch processing, but you can do this way

```
current_page = 0
item_count = Model.count
while item_count > 0
  Model.all.skip(current_page * 1000).limit(1000).each do |item|
    Sunpot.index(item)
  end
  item_count-=1000
  current_page+=1
end
```

But if you are looking for a perfect long time solution i wouldn't recommend this. Let me explain how i handled the same scenario in my app. Instead of doing batch jobs,

- i have created a [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) job which updates the solr index

  ```
  class SolrUpdator
   @queue = :solr_updator

   def self.perform(item_id)
     item = Model.find(item_id)
     #i have used RSolr, u can change the below code to handle sunspot
     solr = RSolr.connect :url => Rails.application.config.solr_path
     js = JSON.parse(item.to_json)
     solr.add js         
   end
  ```

  end
- After adding the item, i just put an entry to the resque queue

  ```
  Resque.enqueue(SolrUpdator, item.id.to_s)
  ```
- Thats all, start the resque and it will take care of everything

Comment: Ramesh, the first block of code you provided works very well for my use case.  It's just a one-time load and index of the data using a script file, so using resque may be overkill for my particular case.  But the batching ability works perfectly!

Comment: This isn't necessary. Mongoid and the underlying Mongo driver already batch queries with a cursor. This keeps the memory footprint small.

Answer (score -3):

As @RyanMcGeary said, you don't need to worry about batching the query. However, indexing objects one at a time is much much slower than batching them.

```
Model.all.to_a.in_groups_of(1000, false) do |records|
  Sunspot.index! records
end
```

Comment: `Model.all.to_a` would load the entire collection into memory.

Comment: That's right, please don't do this: When we're talking about large datasets avoid converting entire collection to array at once: use `Model.find_each` or batch in any way but never `Model.all.to_a`

Comment: Model.find_each is not a Mongoid method. You would use Model.all.each instead.

Answer (score -3):

The following will work for you , just try it

```
Model.all.in_groups_of(1000, false) do |r|
  Sunspot.index! r
end
```

Comment: Loading all the database in memory... duh. The whole point of this is to be able to query documents in batches, if you have 4 million documents you will kill your server by first loading them into a single array, and then another array of groups.

Comment: @rewritten please check the above solution , the same what I given he explained. thanks for explanation Ryan McGeary.

Comment: `in_groups_of` is a Rails Array method, to be used you should convert `Model.all` to an array, which is not recommended at all. The -1 is to warn people to not do that.