# How to download CSV data using ActionController::Live from MongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-csv, server-sent-events, actioncontroller

I have created a CSV downloader in a controller like this

```
format.csv do
  @records  = Model.all

  headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"products.csv\"" 
  headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
end
```

Now I want to create `server sent events` to download CSV from this for optimising purpose. I know I can do this in Rails using `ActionController::Live` but I have have no experience with it.

Can some one explain to me how I can

1. Query records as batches
2. Add records to `stream`
3. Handle `sse` from browser side
4. Write records to CSV files

Correct me if any of my assumptions are wrong. Help me do this in a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid automatically query your records in batches (More info over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8611674/5379362))

To add your records to a CSV file, you should do something like:

```
records = MyModel.all
# By default batch_size is 100, but you can modify it using .batch_size(x)

result = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["attribute1", "attribute2", ...]
  records.each do |r|
    csv << [r.attribute1, r.attribute2, ...]
  end
end

send_data result, filename: 'MyCsv.csv'
```

Remember that [`send_data`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) is an ActionController method!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don´t need SSE for generating a CSV. Just `include ActionController::Live` into the controller to use the *response.stream.write* iterating your collection:

```
include ActionController::Live
...
def some_action
  format.csv do
    # Needed for streaming to workaround Rack 2.2 bug
    response.headers['Last-Modified'] = Time.now.httpdate

    headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"products.csv\""
    headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'

    [1,2,3,4].each do |i|   # --> change it to iterate your DB records
      response.stream.write ['SOME', 'thing', "interesting #{i}", "#{Time.zone.now}"].to_csv

      sleep 1  # some fake delay to see chunking
    end

    ensure
      response.stream.close
    end
  end
```

Try it with curl or similar to see the output line by line:

```
$ curl -i  http://localhost:3000/test.csv
```